# Access "Browser" location

Tags: python, django, geolocation

We all have seen this prompt:

[image]

As far as I know, this is **not** IP-based location. This is device-based location.

I don't want IP-based location because 1) It's not reliable and 2) If the user browses my website with a VPN, the location data is absolutely wrong.

I've searched PyPi.org and DjangoPackages.org but didn't find anything to implement that in my Django app.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Django is a backend service and can't do this. You need to write javascript to trigger this prompt, get the result and POST it to your django app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the browser to ask the user for geolocation you must use javascript.

This snippet from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) demonstrates this.

The latitude and longitude can you then pass forward to the backend.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```